# How to find the smallest value in an array without using C# Math function?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I am using C# and I am doing some questions for revision. I am trying to find the smallest value in a randomly generated array (which I coded). My teacher requires us to find the smallest value in that array without using the .Min function, because this is an algorithm module. Code below shows what I have coded to create the array. Have no idea how to proceed from here. Thank you guys.

```
int[] myRandom = new int[10];
int min = 0;
int max = 19;

Random randNum = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    myRandom[i] = randNum.Next(min, max);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myRandom[i]);
}
```

Comment: That just creates the array and prints it - where is the attempt to find the min value?

Comment: That's what I'm asking you guys, I don't know how to start.

Comment: Seems like homework. As a start: when iterating compare your current value with the previos one. If its smaller you have a new minimum.

Comment: No, all I need is to find the smallest value in the array, then print it, e.g. "The smallest value is 5".

Comment: if (minVal > myRandom[i]) ...

Comment: Puzzling out the steps to problems like this is an *essential* skill required in programming.  You cant base your career on being able to 'google a code'

Comment: I know man but I don't even know where to begin, like if I need to make a new variable or whatever.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but are you really computer science student at a university?  This a very basic question and you even have trouble understanding the solution when it is given to you.

Comment: Well yeah you are being rude actually. I really struggle with problem solving enough as it is and I feel bad for it so you don't need to approach that side of it. I used to be good at pascal when I was in college.

Comment: Is that also why this post is being voted down? Because I don't know how to do this question? Isn't this community about helping people who are struggling with a programming issue?

Comment: The likely reason this is being downvoted is that you didn't show any attempt at solving the problem yourself. What do you think is the way to approach this? If it helps, think about how you would do this by hand on paper. If I gave you a list of numbers, how would you determine which was the smallest? Without showing that you've tried, this question just comes across as "Can you give me the answer to my homework?". I'm not saying that you actually want us to do your work for you, but it comes across that way

Comment: @KevinWells if I did this on paper I would merely pick the lowest number.

Comment: Yes, but how would you pick the lowest number. If someone asked you to prove that it was the lowest number, what would you say? Likely you would say, "I read through the list and kept a mental note of the lowest one I had seen so far, so that when I got to the end I know I had the smallest one." That is essentially what Arturo's answer does. It looks at each number in the list and if it is the lowest one it has seen so far it remembers it.

Comment: See if I had never came here I would not of thought to think of it in that way. It didn't seem obvious to me that I should think in that way. It also didn't seem obvious to put an if statement.

Comment: @parkie1995: kevin the explanation was really good, I think there is no better way to say it. just add about your doubt of the initial value of min: the first value that you keep in mind is the first value of the list, because it is the only one you have so far. It is the same in the code, you start with min = myRandom[0]

Answer (score 9):

The easy way is using `Min()` linq extension method:

```
var min = myRandom.Min();
Console.WriteLine(min);
```

But if you need to do it manually you can do this:

```
//int min = int.MaxValue;                    //This variable stores current min value during each iteration.
int min = myRandom[0];                       //If first value of myRandom is the minimum then ok, you already have it, if not it will be replaced in iterations

for (int i = 0; i < myRandom.Length; i++)
    if (myRandom[i] < min)                   //Compare each value of the array with the current min value
        min = myRandom[i];

Console.WriteLine(min);
```

Comment: Just one thing - that int.MaxValue isn't using a math function in any way is it?

Comment: int.MaxValue is just a number, however you can change it to the first number in myRandom (myRandom[0])

Comment: I am finding the maxvalue thing confusing, I mean why does it say maxvalue when it is the min value we want to find?

Comment: @parkie1995: the idea is start with some big number and in each iteration compare it with the current value of the array and replace it if is lower. But you can start with the first value of myRandom[0].

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Really foreach on an array?

Comment: I just don't get it. And ok I know I can use myRandom[0] instead of .Max but then why 0 when the max would be 19?

Comment: @Frisbee: `foreach (var item in myRandom) if (item < min) min = item;`

Comment: @parkie1995: int.MaxValue refers to a number, not the index in the array.

Comment: @Frisbee: foreach is available for IEnumerable, so is availabe in arrays

Comment: Yea it refers to the number with the MaxValue, and so why does 0 refer to the MaxValue also?

Comment: @parkie199: you can take any value of the array (lets say the first one) as the minimum and reduce it in each iteration

Comment: you can take as initial min value int.MaxValue (2147483647) or just any value of the array myRandom[0], myRandom[5], ... myRandom[19] (but i means to the value in the array, not the index 0, 5 or 19)

Comment: You might at well start on int i = 1;

Comment: @Frisbee: yes, is true

Comment: @parkie1995: dont worry about it. Debug the code step by step checking the values of min and myRandom[i] and you will see how it works.

Comment: Yeah gonna work on my understanding first then I'll take it cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the best solution. **You find the min value and generate the array at the same time**, like this:

```
int minValue = int.MaxValue;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    myRandom[i] = randNum.Next(min, max);
    if (myRandom[i] < minValue)
    {
        minValue = myRandom[i];
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(minValue);
```

By doing this, you don't have to loop the array the second time to find the min value.

Comment: Remember, this is a class assignment. The assignment is to find the smallest value in an array, not how to optimize the code he's written. After all, if you wanted to optimize that code you wouldn't even create the array. You'd just keep track of the smallest number already generated.